# Convert JSON arrays to JSON format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

I am having a problem converting JSON arrays to JSON format data, Currently I am getting my output in this format:

[image]

But I want to have my output in this format:

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
    <?php

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","", "testapp");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM timetable";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $rows[] = $row; 

    }

echo json_encode($rows);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows);
echo "</pre>"; 

?>
```

Comment: The Structure of the Data in the 2 Screenshots seem not to be related at all. The Intended JSON end-result contains keys like `Name` and `Major` but nowhere in the Payload (Array) did any of those Keys appear... Could you relate?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the below mentioned step.

print_r(json_encode($rows));


// Example

<?php
$val = (array('0'=>array('id'=>'2',
                        'name'=>'kmg'),
             '1'=>array('id'=>'3',
                       'name'=>'kumar')));

print_r($val);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
print_r(json_encode($val));

?>

// Result

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => kmg ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => kumar ) ) 

[{"id":"2","name":"kmg"},{"id":"3","name":"kumar"}]
```